# How to add requirements to the token contract: 1) owner has enough tokens and 2) minimum sum of ETH of the receivers before updating balances

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tokens, erc-20, require

Could you check if these lines are correct and will work? In this code I have **two requirements**: I want to check if the **owner has enough tokens** (10 millions tokens) before updating balances and also **send tokens only to addresses with minimum 2 ETH balance**.

```
  function getEthBalance(address _addr) constant
  returns(uint) {
      return _addr.balance;
  }

  function distributeToken(address[] addresses, uint256 _value) onlyOwner {
   for (uint i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
   require(balanceOf[owner] >= 10000000); // FIRST REQUIREMENT
   if (getEthBalance(addresses[i]) <= 200000000000000)) {
      continue;
      }; // SECOND REQUIREMENT
   balances[owner] -= _value;
   balances[addresses[i]] += _value;
   Transfer(owner, addresses[i], _value);
   }
   }
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some suggestions:

Don't write `200000000000000`. It makes the number unreadable.

Instead, you can just write `2 ether`:

```
if (getEthBalance(addresses[i]) <= 2 ether) {
```

Why do you have a `getEthBalance` function if all is does is `.balance` ? You can just do `.balance` in place of calling that function:

```
if (addresses[i].balance <= 2 ether) {
```

You said 'minimum 2 ether'. If you want that, you should use `<` instead of `<=`:

```
if (addresses[i].balance < 2 ether) {
```

To me it seems like it would work, but I won't guarantee it. If you want to know if something will work, you should always test it on a local development chain, or on an Ethereum test network.

Comment: Thank you! You're right, the function getEthBalance is not necessary here.

Comment: @MichaelP Also you can move the first require outside of the for loop, will save some gas if you have more than one address to check.